# Was this 4th grader's creationist quiz on "Dinosaurs: Genesis and the Gospel" real?

Tags: young-earth-creationism

Is this 4th grader's creationist quiz real or a hoax?

[image: Quiz, answers are 1) false; 2) false; 3) 6th; 4) true; 5) plants; 6) dinosaur image; 7) false]

Text:

> 100 A+
> Date: 3/28/13
>
> ### 4th grade Science Quiz: 
> Dinosaurs: Genesis and the Gospel
>
> 1. True or **False**: The earth is billions of years old.
> 2. True or **False**: Dinosaurs lived millions of years ago.
> 3. On what day did God make dinosaurs? **6th**
> 4. **True** or False: Dinosaurs lived with people
> 5. What did people and animals eat in the beginning? **plants**
> 6. Which one fits the Behemoth described in Job 40? (Circle the picture)
>    [elephant image] [rhino image] [**dinosaur image**]
> 7. True or **False**: If an animal has sharp teeth, it must mean it is a meat-eater.

Comment: Off-topic comments deleted. Please take off-topic discussion to [chat].

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yes, it is real.

According to [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/photos/signs/sciencetest.asp) and the school is supposedly [Blue Ridge Christian Academy](https://web.archive.org/web/20130828115628/http://www.brca.us/) in Landrum, South Carolina. There's also a second page linked on the site:

[image: second page of creationist "science" quiz]
<sup>([source](http://www.snopes.com/graphics/quiz2.jpg))</sup>

This is also confirmed by [Answers in Genesis](https://answersingenesis.org/world-religions/atheism/intolerant-atheists-viciously-attack-christian-school/), a noted anti-science, pro-creationist website:

> Today, we bring your attention to another attack on Christian education. A Christian K–12 school in South Carolina, with dedicated and highly qualified Christian teachers, has come under vicious attack by atheists. Why? Because one of its instructors, a fourth-grade teacher, tested her children about biblical creation, science, and dinosaurs (using AiG resources), and she has become (in)famous on many atheist websites and blogs.

Therefore, it seems that all parties agree on this.

Comment: Question+Answer are missing #8-10 in the quiz, so for completeness see: https://legacy-cdn-assets.answersingenesis.org/assets/pdf/2013/4th-grade-science-quiz.pdf

Comment: @DavePhD Link is dead (404).